# How to get object value of data class?

Tags: android

This is my data class main constructor.

```
@Parcelize
data class CharacInfo(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo var category: Int,
    @ColumnInfo var img: Int,
    @ColumnInfo var job: String,
    @ColumnInfo var birth: String,
    @ColumnInfo var onoff: Boolean
) : Parcelable
```

I want to get the value of each parameter of the data class from the service class.
This is my service class.

```
class AlarmService : Service() {

    private var list = ArrayList<CharacInfo>()
    private lateinit var info: CharacInfo

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText("test")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1,notification)
        return START_STICKY

    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

But I can't initialize the info object.
I don't want to insert a new value, I want to get an existing value.
I wanted to create an empty constructor, but I made it because I needed a main constructor in my data class.

Answer (score 0):

For each parameter, you should use **forEach** loop like this

```
 list.forEach {
        val uid = it.uid
        var category = it.category
        var img = it.img
        var job = it.job
        var birth = it.birth
        var onoff = it.onoff
    }
```

Comment: thank you but how can i get the value??.

Comment: Unresolved reference: job